# Cannot read property 'grid' of undefined in modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal  that I want to display pre-selected rows in. However, I keep getting a 'cannot read 'grid' of undefined' error. The UI Grids are defined within the modal, and I declare two Grid Apis with two different names. Here is my code:

This launches the modal:

```
    //edit user group
    $scope.editSelectedGroup = function(){
        //get the selected row
        var row = $scope.gridApiInfo.selection.getSelectedRows();

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'userGroupModal.html',
            controller: 'UserGroupModalController',
            resolve: {
                modalTitle: function () {
                    return "Edit User Group"
                },
                allDepartments: function () {
                    return $scope.allDepartments;
                },
                allRegions: function() {
                    return $scope.allRegions;
                },
                isEdit: function(){
                    return true;
                },
                row: function(){
                    return row[0];
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the modal controller:

```
    .controller('UserGroupModalController',function($scope,$modalInstance,$modal,$window,modalTitle,allDepartments,allRegions,isEdit,row,referenceDataService){

    $scope.modalTitle = modalTitle;
    $scope.isEdit = isEdit;
    $scope.allDepartments= allDepartments;
    $scope.allRegions = allRegions;

    $scope.form= {
        value: "",
        description: "",
        departments: [],
        regions: []
    };

    $scope.departmentsGrid = {
        enableRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) { 
            $scope.deptGridApi= gridApi;
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {name: 'Name', field: 'name'}
        ],
        data: $scope.allDepartments
    };

    $scope.regionsGrid = {
        enableRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: true,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApiRegions = gridApi;
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {name: 'Name', field: 'name'}
        ],
        data: $scope.allRegions
    };

    if ($scope.isEdit){
        $scope.form.value = row.value;
        $scope.form.description = row.description;

        //pushing selected depts
        angular.forEach(row.departments, function(department) {
            var deptElementPos=angular.findIndexOf($scope.allDepartments, department.id);
            $scope.form.departments.push($scope.allDepartments[deptElementPos]);
        });

        //pushing selected regions
        angular.forEach(row.regions, function(region) {
            var regionElementPos=angular.findIndexOf($scope.allRegions, region.id);
            $scope.form.regions.push($scope.allRegions[regionElementPos]);
        });

        //setting pre-selected rows
        angular.forEach($scope.form.departments, function(department) {
            $scope.deptGridApi.grid.rows.map(function (row) {
                if (row.entity.id == department.id) {
                    row.setSelected(true);
                    $log.log("row selected: " + row.entity.id);
                }
            });
        });

        angular.forEach($scope.form.regions, function(region) {
            $scope.gridApiRegions.grid.rows.map(function (row) {
                if (row.entity.id == region.id) {
                    row.setSelected(true);
                    $log.log("row selected region: " + row.entity.id);
                }
            });
        });

        $scope.form.id = row.id;
    }

    $scope.close = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss();
    };
})
```

When I click the button to launch the modal, no modal shows up - instead I get a console error saying that it 'Cannot read property 'grid' of undefined' at the line with $scope.deptGridApi.grid.rows.map. Anyone have any suggestions for how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Getting selected rows using deptGridApi and gridApiRegions work - I wrote a test function activated by clicking a button in the modal, shown below:

```
        $scope.getDeptandRegions= function(form){
            $log.log($scope.gridApiRegions.selection.getSelectedRows());
            $log.log($scope.deptGridApi.selection.getSelectedRows())  
         };
```

These log the selected rows fine, even though this also uses the grid APIs. Is it this is only fired after I press a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cannot read property 'grid' of undefined' at the line with $scope.deptGridApi.grid.rows.map
```

means that :

```
$scope.deptGridApi === undefined
```

Looking at your code it is because `onRegisterApi` is either

- Never called
- Called with "undefined" as paramener

*If you can provide a working code snippet I may be able to help you better*

Comment: So onRegisterApi is called within departmentsGrid when I declare it - is this not the right way to declare onRegisterApi? Do I separate it out and declare it on its own?

Comment: In the code you provided `onRegisterApi` isn't called. It is declared as a function doing `$scope.deptGridApi= gridApi;` but at no point I see a `$scope.departmentsGrid.onRegisterApi(yourDeptGripApi)`

Comment: Hmmm I thought that it gets naturally called as shown in the documentation when a grid is created as its a callback function: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/102_sorting ...I tried separating it out as so: 
`$scope.departmentsGrid.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi){
                $scope.deptGridApi= gridApi;
            };`

but in console it seems to just skip over the body of OnRegisterApi.